# storybook react --> stories not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook, storybook-addon

I have upgraded the storybook of a project to 6.5.16 and am currently facing the problem, that the stories are not showing. The sidebar shows story titles and the story itself, but clicking on either doesn't do anything.  I am getting a devtools warning

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:8080/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

but not sure whether that's relevant.

main.ts

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.tsx"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport",
  ],
  features: {
    storyStoreV7: true,
  },
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
  },
  staticDirs: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../resources")],
  webpackFinal: async (config: any) => {   
    if (config.resolve?.alias) {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        "@style-variables": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/styles/variables"),
      };
    }

    if (config.plugins) {
      config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "[name].css" }));
    }

    if (config.module?.rules) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {},
          },
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: [
                  path.resolve(__dirname, "./../../../node_modules"),
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

Also got a preview.js

```
addParameters({
  docs: {
    container: DocsContainer,
    page: DocsPage,
  },
});

function loadStories() {
  require("./../dist/index.js");
}

const storyWrapper = (story) => (
  <div className="storywrapper" style={{ margin: 35 }}>
    {story()}
  </div>
);

addDecorator(
  withInfo({
    inline: true,
    header: false,
    source: true,
    maxPropsIntoLine: 1,
  })
);

addDecorator(storyWrapper);
configure(loadStories, module);
```

and this as an example story:

```
export default {
  title: 'Selector',
  decorators: [withKnobs],
};

export const Default = () => (
  <Component
    isDisabled={ isDisabled() }
    items={ SELECTOR_ITEMS }
    selectedItem={ SELECTOR_ITEMS[0] }
  />
);
```

(left the imports out)

As I wrote, the stories seem loaded but are not showing. Please help :)

Comment: Please do you have all stack tracer errors?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10469
Seems to be related to the problem.
The warning seems to not have a relation with this error

Try cleaning the Storybook cache and running again:

```
rm -rf node_modules/.cache/storybook
```

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13795#issuecomment-773622951

Also, try use the `component` config:

```
export default {
  title: 'Selector',
  component: Component, // <-- here
  decorators: [withKnobs],
};
```

Comment: this helps with the devtools warning/error, but unfortunately still doesn't fix the storybook problem. :(

Comment: yep, I edit my comment. Seems to be some error in the component.
Try to render some basic component that is working and start changing with baby steps.

Comment: thanks, trying right now. the checkmark thing also didn't help. How should the src/index.ts look like? Mine only says "import './stories';"

Comment: @Applecow try to use the  component: Component config in the export default object configuration

Comment: thanks, but still does not work :/

Comment: adding a preview-body.htlm file with some div content works. but there still is a div with the text "Sorry, but you either have no stories or none are selected somehow."

Comment: but u have some components working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254381/discussion-between-applecow-and-fabio-ribeiro-de-carvalho).